# AWS subnet’s using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, private-subnet, aws-databricks

I have a set of subnet’s how do i assign the subnets which are available automatically using terraform?
Ex : [“subnet-a”,”subnet-b”,”subnet-c”, “subnet-d”]

I want to pick the two available subnets from given set for module A and module B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [random_shuffle](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/random/latest/docs/resources/shuffle):

```
resource "random_shuffle" "az" {
  input        = [“subnet-a”,”subnet-b”,”subnet-c”]
  result_count = 2
}
```

then to get the actual result:

```
random_shuffle.az.result
```